# 2014 dodge avenger - Brake Squealing and Grinding Sounds, Front and Rear

Tags: brakes, noise, dodge, avenger

Have a 2014 Dodge Avenger purchased in August 2015. I am leasing this car.

First problem is my brakes. Just got them placed on 2 weeks ago. The next day they were grinding and squeaking very loud. Took it back to the shop they told me it was brake dust. Drove home and same problem. Now I just got the back brakes placed on as well and the same thing. This time a different shop.

No one can tell me what’s the problem and I’m so afraid my brakes are going lock up and go out.

Can someone explain this situation to me please?

Comment: This post is very hard to read in all caps - it's reads like someone screaming at me.

Comment: The shop that replaced the bakes that needs to fix anything that is wrong with them.

Comment: Are they really making a grinding sound?  Can you feel the grinding a bit in the floorboard or the steering wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Brake squealing is a complex problem and the fastest and least frustrating way to solve it is to replace the pads and rotors at the same time and use quality pads and rotors.  Having the rotors resurfaced is an alternative to replacing them with new ones and might be cheaper.